# PostgreSQL function definition in SQuirreL: unterminated dollar-quoted string

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, squirrel-sql

I have the following function definition for a PostgreSQL 9.3.4 database:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_modified_timestamp()  
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
  BEGIN
    NEW.modified_at = now();
    RETURN NEW; 
  END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

When I try to execute this in SQuirreL (3.5.3 or 3.6), I get the following error:

```
Error: ERROR: unterminated dollar-quoted string at or near "$$
 BEGIN
     NEW.modified_at = now()"
  Position: 77
SQLState:  42601
ErrorCode: 0
```

So far I've learned this [can be mitigated by using single quotes](http://sourceforge.net/p/squirrel-sql/feature-requests/320/) to delimit the function body like so:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_modified_timestamp()  
RETURNS TRIGGER AS '
  BEGIN
    NEW.modified_at = now();
    RETURN NEW; 
  END;
' LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Still I would like to know if this can't be solved otherwise - I think it must be possible since [Flyway](http://flywaydb.org/) can execute this script and it uses the exact same JDBC driver that is configured in SQuirreL.

---

**Update:** *@a_horse_with_no_name* noted that this error has nothing to do with the JDBC driver, but with how SQuirreL parses the SQL statement and splits it into chunks before sending them to the database. Thus the remaining question is: **Can SQuirreL send a query raw/unparsed?** I've searched quite a bit couldn't find a way to do that.

Comment: SQLFiddle has the same issue, but there the single quotes function body don't even solve the problem.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the JDBC driver. I guess Squirrel doesn't know that the text between $$ is actually a string literal and only sends the function definition up to the first `;`. Is Squirrel able to to send a query _without parsing it_ to the database? It works in SQFiddle if you use a different delimiter: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ce3fa3/2

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can change the statement separator so the statement is not split on a `;`:

Go to: *Session* → *Session Properties* → *SQL* → *Statement Separator*

Even though you can't change it to an empty string, you can change it for example to `//`, which allows execution of the statement in the question.