# PostgreSQL 10 function creation not working

Tags: postgresql, stored-functions, heidisql

I have the following query, which I've modified for my database tables/columns, but it is not working upon execution:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION delete_data_antique(resourceid integer) 
RETURNS TABLE(metrics_values_id int4) AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY 
    delete from metrics_values 
    where resource_id = $1 
      and time < (current_timestamp - interval '38 day') 
      and id not in
       (select id 
        from (select distinct on (time_week) 
                id, time, date_trunc('week', time) time_week 
          from metrics_values
          where resource_id = $1 
            and time < (current_timestamp - interval '38 day') 
          order by time_week, time desc)
          as first_in_week_versions) 
    returning id; 
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Error message is as follows

[image: sql function creation error]

I'm new to creating functions in SQL, and have been reading the docs, but not sure where/how it's not actually working.

Comment: The problem is in your client program which cannot properly interpret semicolon. Use PgAdmin or psql if you do not know how to force your software to work correctly.

Comment: Unrelated, but: you don't need PL/pgSQL for this. A plain `language sql` function would do

Comment: Which SQL client are you using?

Comment: See e.g. here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30211053 or

Comment: Still relatively new to  programming functions.  Most of my work has been basic and structured queries in the past. 

SQL client is Heidi, which I know has experimental support.  I'll look at the links provided.

Will star when I figure it out and get it working. Thanks, @a_horse_with_no_name